# Date Conversion in objective c?

Tags: iphone

I have an array containing the String objects with this format 22/04/2011.My question is that how can I change this string into the `yyyy-mm-dd format`. I am using `NSDateFormatter` but it's not working.

Comment: First, what code do you have so far? And second, what exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: -1 : And third, there are some many same thread and before searching those why you guys again ask the same question..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formater setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
        NSDate *date2 = [formater dateFromString:@"22/04/2011"];
        [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
        NSString *result = [formater stringFromDate:date2];
NSLog(@"Date - %@",result);
```

And For Reference - http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html

Answer (score 1):

The real thing to know that when you convert a string date to NSDate using NSDateFormatter using any of the above mentioned methods, you will always get the NSDate object in Local TimeZone. So when coding the method for date conversion you need to consider this factor.

Hope this helps..

-:samfisher

Answer (score 0):

Here how I do this ... This code works ... Try this

```
NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSString* currentDateString = [df stringFromDate:currentDate];
[df release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date2 = [formater dateFromString:@"2010-11-17"];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
    NSString *result = [formater stringFromDate:date2];
```